# Disadvantage to using phpMyAdmin for database design?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In school I learned SQL commands and always used the command line to do database.  Now that I'm in a professional environment, without realizing it I've migrated to strictly using phpMyAdmin with MySQL.  It started off as an easy "just this one time" solution, and now I don't touch the command line unless absolutely necessary.

Is there a disadvantage that I'm not seeing?  Should I go old school and write my Create Tables on Notepad++ and copy them in to my command line client?  I have little foresight due to my lack of experience.  Is there a more robust solution than phpMyAdmin that I should consider?  I guess my specific question is, what method should I use as a junior dev that wants to improve their SQL skill in the long run?

Comment: There is no right or wrong way. Do whatever works for *you*.

Comment: Using a gui won't improve your sql skills it will improve your gui skills but won't help if you move to an environment where Toad (for example) is the development tool.